# I need an easier and more efficient way that works for my website formatting (uses shapes in CSS and HTML)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to design a page that has 24 circles in each bottom quadrant, in stacks of two (so top rows in bottom left each having 12 circles and the same for the bottom right)

Can anybody tell me why it's not letting me make more circles even though I have it more than 4 times for the top circles? And if anyone knows an easier way to do this please let me know. Also any further learning resources to further get the formatting of HTML + CSS + JSS down. Thanks.

HERE IS MY CODE:

HTML:
{

```
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>
  <span class="BottomLeftseat"></span>

 <span2 class = "TopLeftseat" ></span2>
 <span2 class = "TopLeftseat" ></span2>
 <span2 class = "TopLeftseat" ></span2>
 <span2 class = "TopLeftseat" ></span2>
 <span2 class = "TopLeftseat" ></span2>
 <span2 class = "TopLeftseat" ></span2>
```

}

CSS:

```
body {

  background-color: white;

}


.TopLeftseat {
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;


}

.BottomLeftseat {
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0%;
  top: 600px;


}

.TopLeftseat {
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -400px;
  top: 500px;


}

.TopRightseat {
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0%;
  top: 600px;

}

.BottomRightseat {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: Go for Flex-Grid design using CSS, It will help.

Comment: Why are you using `span2` as an element, this is incorrect `HTML`? Change `span2` to `span`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not really the tool for this job.  I recommend using SVG, which is a markup language similar to HTML, but with elements for vector graphics.  For example:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes

Comment: Using vectors is great but for the sake of 24 circles I don't think it is really needed and the OP is asking why the current `css` isn't giving the expected output so unless you can provide information of the benefit(s) to change to `SVG` and give some example I think this would be better posted as a comment/recommendation rather than a answer/solution.

Comment: @NewToJS The benefits are obvious... a direct route to exactly what is desired rather than a hackjob of questionable CSS to position HTML elements.  SVG is purpose-built for this sort of thing, can be put directly in the HTML document, and can still be styled with the CSS in a consistent manner.  Additionally, if you read the title of the question you will see that OP is asking for an easier and more efficient method... which is exactly what SVG provides.

Comment: To many the benefits are obvious but to those who wish to learn from this question and your answer it isn't too obvious.

Comment: @NewToJS If you have a suggestion of how to make it more obvious than showing example code of a `<circle>` element when the question is asking how to make circles, and something beyond my previous comment indicating that this is a direct route, I'm all ears.  I'm quite enthusiastic about making things easy for folks wanting to learn... that's the whole reason I'm here answering questions.  I just don't see what could be added without creating confusion.  The person asking the question should/could ask for clarification when they see the answer.

Comment: Maybe add the details of your comment into the question. *"rather than a hackjob"* - *"SVG is purpose-built for this sort of thing, can be put directly in the HTML document, and can still be styled with the CSS in a consistent manner."* That little bit of detail explains the reason for your recommendation and gives reason to look into using `SVG`. Details like that make a answer/solution better when dealing with a question like this. "My opinion" Just want to help improve the answer for the OP and others who might stumble on it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys. I'm going to look into SVG. But do any of you have a solution to this problem in HTML?  Similarly, could I use SVG for all browsers? And is SVG just an extension of html or not?

Comment: Also which language should I try and learn if my goal is making web applications in an efficient manner, scaling from small to large?

Comment: @FirstLast SVG works in most any browser.  It's not an extension of HTML... it's a separate thing, but browsers can render it.  You can embed an SVG document within an HTML document.  As far as what to learn... these are unrelated to each other.  They're tools for different jobs.  If you're laying out documents, document-like things, or general web applications, HTML is what you want.  If you need to put shapes, paths, specific layouts, animations (beyond what's provided for in CSS transforms), etc., then you want SVG.